# Limit of given sequence:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

While working I encountered an expression

$\pi(n)= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^k),$ where $0<x<1.$

I need to find the limit of this expression as $n\to \infty.$
My calculation gives me the limit as $1$ since $x^{k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty.$ Please help me correct this.

Comment: $\log \pi(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \log(1+x^k) \ge \log 2$, so the limit cannot be one.

Comment: This is the generating function for the number of partitions into distinct parts. Oodles of information at http://oeis.org/A000009 and wherever partition identities are discussed.

Comment: I guess your calculations gave you the limit when $x$ tends to $0$, and not when $n$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Have you had a look at the link I gave, J.Y.?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I can see some integer sequences $x_n=x_{n-2}+x_{n-3}$ but couldn't relate it with the limit of my expression.

Comment: At that link it gives an asymptotic formula for the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. A version of that formula is $${e^{\pi\sqrt{n/3}}\over4\cdot3^{1/4}n^{3/4}}$$ which grows more slowly than any exponential function, and that's enough to prove that your function converges for all $x$ with $|x|<1$. As to what it converges to, I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to get. It doesn't converge to anything like $\cos x$ or $\log x$ that you'd recognize from undergraduate Calculus. $\prod_1^{\infty}(1+x^k)$ is a function not expressible in finite terms (continued)

Comment: (continued) in terms of power functions and trig functions and exponentials and logarithms and such.

Comment: Actually, the convergence proof is much simpler. $\prod_1^{\infty}(1+x^k)$ converges since $\sum_1^{\infty}x^k$ converges (for $|x|<1$). But this doesn't tell you much about what it converges to.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This does help to some extent. I suppose then we may it as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^k)=O(2)$ for $0<x<1.$

Comment: $O(2)$ would mean it's bounded as a function of $x$. It isn't. The infinite product is unbounded as $x\to1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If the sequence converges, then it must be bounded.

Comment: For each $x$, it's bounded as $n$ goes to infinity. But the infinite product is unbounded, as $x\to1$. Think about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_0^nx^k$. For $|x|<1$, $\sum_0^nx^k$ converges to $(1-x)^{-1}$ as $n\to\infty$. But $(1-x)^{-1}$ is unbounded as $x\to1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Totally agreed. Can we give some values to the above mentioned sequence as $n \to \infty$ and $0<x<1$ in the form of big O notation or something else?

Comment: Probably. The function $f(x)=\prod_1^{\infty}(1+x^k)$ has been studied for a long time, I'm sure there are results of the type you want in the literature. I'm just not on top of them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for giving your time on this.